# Swift reduce and sum with condition ranking array

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, swift5

I would like count the number of victory and sum all points.

I wold to use flatmap map and reduce, to reduce the complexity. For scure I can obtain it with for cycles

The problem is that in allMatch, I can have different teamID (team can play in single, or couple of person) and doesn't matter the order (for example the teamID 1,2 is equal to teamID 2,1

```
struct InfoMatch: Hashable {
    let teamId: Set<Int>
    let rank: Int
    let mPoints: Int
    let vPoints: Int
}
```

All matches is array of array, because it returns the info of each team for each match, in this example the first match done with 2 teams, te last one with 3 teams

```
let allMatch: [[InfoMatch]] = [
    [InfoMatch(teamId:[1,2],rank:1,mPoints: 200,vPoints: 0),InfoMatch(teamId:[3,4],rank:2,mPoints: 100,vPoints: 0)],
    [InfoMatch(teamId:[1,2],rank:2,mPoints: 0,vPoints: 10),InfoMatch(teamId:[4,3],rank:1,mPoints: 0,vPoints: 20)],
    [InfoMatch(teamId:[2,1],rank:1,mPoints: 40,vPoints: 0),InfoMatch(teamId:[3,4],rank:2,mPoints: 30,vPoints: 0),InfoMatch(teamId:[5,6],rank:3,mPoints: 5,vPoints: 0)]
]
let winners = allMatch.map{$0.filter{$0.rank == 1}}
let losers = allMatch.map{$0.filter{$0.rank != 1}}

print(winners)
```

prints:

> [[__lldb_expr_7.InfoMatch(teamId: Set([1, 2]), rank: 1, mPoints: 200,
>   vPoints: 0)], [__lldb_expr_7.InfoMatch(teamId: Set([3, 4]), rank: 1,
>   mPoints: 0, vPoints: 20)], [__lldb_expr_7.InfoMatch(teamId: Set([1,
>   2]), rank: 1, mPoints: 40, vPoints: 0)]]

I would like an array that returns

```
teamID: victoryCount: loserCount: mPoints: vPoints:
```

for that example:

> teamID:1,2 victoryCount:2 loserCount:1 mPoints:240 vPoints:10
>   teamID:3,4 victoryCount:1 loserCount:2 mPoints:130 vPoints:20
>   teamID:5,6 victoryCount:0 loserCount:1 mPoints:5 vPoints:0

Comment: Is it correct that you are using an array in an array? Or should it simply be an array of `InfoMatch`es?

Comment: what does mPoints and vPoints mean?

Comment: It’s correct, array of array, it’s the result of each team for each match. The mPoint it’s the point that the team obtain a the and of the match. vPoint are the same but for different type of match. So if I’ve mPoint, vPoint is 0, and vice versa

Comment: teamID is an array, doesn’t that mean it contains id of the home team and the away team?

Comment: Teamid contain an array of different players, for example te first item, playerid 1 and playerid 2 is one team, vs player 3 and player 4 that is the opposite team

Comment: I don't think there is a simple one line solution to this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really wonder if using *flatmap map and reduce* can *reduce the complexity*, but you can use `reduce` in this way.

First, you say you want *teamID: victoryCount: loserCount: mPoints: vPoints:*, then you should better define the type to represent it:

```
struct MatchStats {
    var teamID: Set<Int>
    var victoryCount: Int
    var loserCount: Int
    var mPoints: Int
    var vPoints: Int
}

//For convenience...
extension MatchStats {
    init(teamID: Set<Int>) {
        self.teamID = teamID
        victoryCount = 0
        loserCount = 0
        mPoints = 0
        vPoints = 0
    }
}

//For debugging...
extension MatchStats: CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description: String {
        let teamIDStr = teamID.sorted().map(String.init).joined(separator: ",")
        return "teamID:\(teamIDStr) victoryCount:\(victoryCount) loserCount:\(loserCount) mPoints:\(mPoints) vPoints:\(vPoints)"

    }
}
```

And use it as follows in `reduce` with `flatMap`:

```
let teamStats: [Set<Int>: MatchStats] = allMatch.flatMap{$0}.reduce(into: [:]) {result, info in
    result[info.teamId, default: MatchStats(teamID: info.teamId)].victoryCount += info.rank == 1 ? 1 : 0
    result[info.teamId]!.loserCount += info.rank == 1 ? 0 : 1
    result[info.teamId]!.mPoints += info.mPoints
    result[info.teamId]!.vPoints += info.vPoints
}

print(teamStats.values)
```

Output:

> ```
> [teamID:1,2 victoryCount:2 loserCount:1 mPoints:240 vPoints:10, teamID:3,4 victoryCount:1 loserCount:2 mPoints:130 vPoints:20, teamID:5,6 victoryCount:0 loserCount:1 mPoints:5 vPoints:0]
> ```

(The output may be in random order on each invocation. But sorting it is another issue.)

---

Do you think using `reduce` is much better than this?

```
var teamStats: [Set<Int>: MatchStats] = [:]
for match in allMatch {
    for info in match {
        teamStats[info.teamId, default: MatchStats(teamID: info.teamId)].victoryCount += info.rank == 1 ? 1 : 0
        teamStats[info.teamId]!.loserCount += info.rank == 1 ? 0 : 1
        teamStats[info.teamId]!.mPoints += info.mPoints
        teamStats[info.teamId]!.vPoints += info.vPoints
    }
}

print(teamStats.values)
```

Comment: I like your solution! As the guide says, the reduce function is with Complexity O(n), where n is the length of the sequence. So I think is quickly respect a for inside for that is not O(n). Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @SimonePistecchia, When you read Big-O notation, it is important to know what `n` means. In my `for`-in-`for` example,  it is `O(m × k)` where `m` is the size of outer Array and `k` is the average size of the inner. And in the `reduce` version, it is `O(n)` where `n = m × k`. Both have equivalent time-complexity.